# While loop in C# going infinite

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application

Below is my code

```
namespace ProgrammingTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GUESS THE ANSWER");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input");

            int input1 = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            while (input1 != 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try agian");
            }
            if (input1 == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are a winner");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (input1 < 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOOOOO low");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (input1 > 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOOOO high");
                Console.ReadLine();          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i am putting while condition but still unable to proceed.It's going infinite loop

Here i want to apply a condition that if the user puts a number other than 4 then it should come to starting and user should again enter the number. Now its happening that its closing the console app. How to put the while loo

Comment: You're going to have to `ReadKey` in the loop too, and check for `4`, and break, etc. When you do `WriteLine` in the loop, it's not going to just back up to the `int intpu1...` line. It just continues going because `input1` _is always 4_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, please check

```
     namespace ProgrammingTesting
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GUESS THE ANSWER");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input");
        int input1 = 0;
        while (input1 != 4)
        {
            input1 = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));


            if (input1 == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are a winner");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (input1 < 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOOOOO low");


            }
            else if (input1 > 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TOOOO high");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Remove Console.Readline() , so that you dont need to enter doble time

Answer (score 2):

You're only changing the value of `input1` before the loop starts. Since you're never changing it again, it will continue to loop forever.

EDIT : You might want to consider doing the following for your loop:

```
int input1 = 0;
while (input1 != 4)
      {
        input1 = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

        if (input1 == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a winner");
        }
        else if (input1 < 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TOOOOO low");
          Console.WriteLine("Try agian");

        }
        else if (input1 > 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TOOOO high");
          Console.WriteLine("Try agian");

        }    
}
```

Comment: Its not happening , when i am entering number other than 4 its exectuing, but it should complete the process untill i complete the correct guess which is 4

Answer (score 2):

add

```
input1 = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

at the end of your while loop, or input1 will never be changed.

But that won't be enough.

You should do (not fine, but working)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GUESS THE ANSWER");


    int answer;
    var success = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input");
    while (!success) {

       var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

       if (!Int32.TryParse(userInput, out answer))
          Console.WriteLine("You must enter an integer");

       else {
          if (answer < 4)
             Console.WriteLine("Too low");

          else if (answer > 4)
             Console.WriteLine("Too high");

          else {
             Console.WriteLine("Grats !");
             success = true;
          }
        }
      if (!success)
         Console.WriteLine("Try again !");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `input1` doesn't change anywhere inside the loop. So, naturally, if the loop is entered once, it's entered every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (input1 != 4)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Try agian");

  }
```

In the code above, the value of `input1` never changes, so it loops forever

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your indentation and you can see your while block contains only the Console.WriteLine and not the input check so the input1 won't change and your loop is infinite.

If you remove the } under Console.WriteLine and you put it to the end you will be able to stop the loop with 4 typed in input.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra `}` right above the `if (input1 == 4)` that is closing the while loop, so the while loop never exits because it has no code inside of it. Move that curly brace down below the `if else`.

Comment: -1. Even if he makes those changes the value of `input1` never changes, and the loop remains infinite.